# position AnchorPoint of a sprite in Cocos2d

Tags: javascript, sprite, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js, anchorpoint

I'm rotating a wheel in **cocos2d-js**.

position of my wheel sprite -

```
sprite.setPosition(cc.p(size.width/2, size.height/2));
```

Anchor of the sprite -

```
sprite.setAnchorPoint(cc.p(0.5, 0.5));
```

But when I rotate the wheel, the sprite comes off from the center, rotating and **moving** at the same time. As if, it's rotating relative to another point, not the center of the wheel. I'm thinking the issue is with the **setAnchorPoint**.

Any idea how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine to me. You can try the other syntax -- one without cc.p. Although it should not make any difference.

It could be that some part of rest of the code has an issue. Check out this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4M-GW0rVeA) for reference.